# Hibernate-envers + Liquebase(ddl-auto=none). Possible to use?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

My question concerns **hibernate-envers** lib.
I've **springboot** project with **liquibase** + **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none**. Therefore if add Hibernate-envers into it, schema some_table_aud, revinfo etc. creation is needed. I realize official docs *https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html*, but didn't found it enough understood embed in my project.
Problem: Liquibase had executed sql file with audit schema below, but haven't fillful with audit data after create/update/delete entities(*resource*, *support_program*).

Did someone has success usage experience Liquebase(ddl-auto=none) + Hibernate-envers?
thank you in advance)

```
create sequence if not exists hibernate_sequence;

CREATE TABLE revinfo
(
    rev integer ,
    revtstmp  bigint NOT NULL,
    user_id bigint ,
    CONSTRAINT pk_revinfo PRIMARY KEY (rev)
);

ALTER TABLE revinfo ADD CONSTRAINT
    fk_revinfo_user_id_users_id
    FOREIGN KEY ( user_id ) REFERENCES users(id);

CREATE INDEX revinfo_user_id_idx ON revinfo USING btree (user_id);

CREATE TABLE cross_revinfo_users
(
    user_id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    revinfo_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_cross_revinfo_users PRIMARY KEY (user_id, revinfo_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_cross_revinfo_users_user_id FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_cross_revinfo_users_revinfo_id FOREIGN KEY(revinfo_id) REFERENCES revinfo(rev)
);

CREATE TABLE resources_aud
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL ,
    rev INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    REVTYPE SMALLINT ,
    REVEND INTEGER ,
    created_at timestamp NULL ,
    eosl_date timestamp NULL ,
    support_program_id BIGINT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT pk_resources_aud PRIMARY KEY ( id, rev )
);

ALTER TABLE resources_aud ADD CONSTRAINT
    fk_resources_aud_rev_revinfo_rev
    FOREIGN KEY ( rev ) REFERENCES revinfo(rev);

ALTER TABLE resources_aud ADD CONSTRAINT
    fk_resources_aud_revend_revinfo_rev
    FOREIGN KEY ( REVEND ) REFERENCES revinfo(rev);

CREATE INDEX resources_aud_rev_idx ON resources_aud USING btree (rev);
CREATE INDEX resources_aud_revend_idx ON resources_aud USING btree (REVEND);

CREATE TABLE support_programs_aud
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL ,
    rev INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    REVTYPE SMALLINT ,
    REVEND INTEGER ,
    created_at timestamp NULL ,
    title VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT pk_support_programs_aud PRIMARY KEY ( id, rev )
);

ALTER TABLE support_programs_aud ADD CONSTRAINT
    fk_support_programs_aud_rev_revinfo_rev
    FOREIGN KEY ( rev ) REFERENCES revinfo(rev);

ALTER TABLE support_programs_aud ADD CONSTRAINT
    fk_support_programs_aud_revend_revinfo_rev
    FOREIGN KEY ( REVEND ) REFERENCES revinfo(rev);

CREATE INDEX support_programs_aud_rev_idx ON support_programs_aud USING btree (rev);
CREATE INDEX support_programs_aud_revend_idx ON support_programs_aud USING btree (REVEND);
```

Comment: How did you [configure](https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html#configuration) envers?

Comment: Due to tremendous entity class won't attach it here.
Annotation @AuditTable(value = "resources_aud") and entity and @Audited(withModifiedFlag = true) for fileds in it.
I did the same with ddl-auto=create and succedded.